# Filter duplicated items from enumerable

Tags: c#

I have an unordered enumeration that may contain duplicates, and I want to remove ALL items that have duplicates, and keep only those that occur only once in the original enumeration.

Example: A and C are removed since they occur more than once:

input {A,C,B,A,C,D,A}
output {B,D}

A quick and dirty implementation could be:

```
IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
   items.Where(item => items.Count(x => x.Equals(item)) == 1);
}
```

Obviously not quick or elegant.

The example below is still quadratic (slightly faster), but requires a ToList() call on the input.

```
IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    List<T> src = items.ToList();
    for(int i=0; i<src.Count; i++)
    {
       if (src.IndexOf(src[i], i+1) < 0)
         yield return src[i]; 
    }
}
```

How would you do this if you wanted it to be reasonably compact and readable (code wise) while still not brain-dead slow like these implementations?

Comment: You could group by itself, then discard groups of size greater than 1. Not optimal but midlly readable and sub-quadratic.

Comment: to be honest, the "quick and dirty" looks "elegant and speedy", much prefer than using groupby.

Comment: after using some stopwatches, the first "dirty" line outperfoms Brad's groupby, and to be honest, it's perfectly readable when the line above starts with // ;)

Comment: @ericosg: I'd like to see those benchmarks, because 500k elements took [no time at all](http://ideone.com/RpgD87).

Comment: indeed, much faster, my test data was too weak. FYI don't forget a .ToList(); between your stopwatches, otherwise they aren't counting actual execution (unless you wrap the output also in the sw).

Comment: @ericosg: Good point. [`.ToList()`](http://ideone.com/35FQg2) ran slightly slower, but still fast @ 580k entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ makes this pretty easy with `GroupBy`:

```
IEnumerable<String> foo = new[]{ "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "D", "A" };
Ienumerable<String> result = foo.GroupBy (x => x)          // A=>3,C=>2,B=>1,D=>1
                               .Where(x => x.Count() == 1) // B=>1,D=>1
                               .Select (x => x.Key);       // B,D
```

1. Group them by value
2. Filter out those with only 1 entry
3. Select the original value

Not sure what you need for performance, but I tend to find GroupBys readable myself.

Comment: Seems like the best answer I can think of too.

Comment: Either way, you're looking at another structure to house which has matches, and how many of them. GroupBy does this elegantly (imho) while still staying concise.

Comment: Would making use of PLINQ improve the performance some how? If there were hundreds of duplicates? .AsParallel, just an idea to look into?

Split the enumerable into chunks to be processed by separately, then merge the results or something similar to that.

Comment: @PatrickMagee, if you split the data, you may end up with the joined chunks having duplicates (separately chunks are OK, but together duplicates occur)

Comment: @PatrickMagee: Going through half a million records is [pretty fast](http://ideone.com/RpgD87).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `O(N)` time.

Algorithm:

- Create a dictionary [T, count] -  (*O(1)*)
- Scan through the inputs - (*O(N)*), insert an item - *(O(1))* or increment the count - *(O(1))*
- Scan the dictionary for items with count of 1 - (*O(N)*)

This solution requires two full scans: one of the input, second of the result dictionary. Although, it is not LINQ, but may actually work faster than LINQ.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = new[] { "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "D", "A" };
        var result = Filter(input);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<T, int>();

        //first scan of the input
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                dictionary[item]++;
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary[item] = 1;
            }
        }

        //second scan
        return from x in dictionary
                where x.Value == 1
                select x.Key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using sets:

```
IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

HashSet<T> itemsToKeep = new HashSet<T>(comparer );
HashSet<T> itemsToRemove = new HashSet<T>(comparer );

foreach(T item in items)
{
   if (itemsToRemove.Add(item))
   {
       continue;
   }
   itemsToKeep.Add(item);
}

itemsToKeep.ExceptWith(itemsToRemove);
```

---

If possible, you can use a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation to speed up performance of sets.

Comment: might be a bit of an overkill?

Comment: @ericosg,  I am almost sure the two loops are unavoidable (`ExceptWith` is the second loop). The built-in set modification operations might be optimal enough. A good custom comparer for `T` could also prove useful. Do you mean the `Add` operations to the set are too slow?